# Why does navigator.device.capture.captureVideo sometimes show the Picture Camera instead of the video camera?

Tags: ios, cordova, opentok, tokbox

Sometimes when calling navigator.device.capture.captureVideo() in my iOS PhoneGap application the picture camera comes up instead of the video camera. Any idea why this might be happening?

It seems like it may be a memory issue as it does happen after a TokBox WebRTC chat session quite frequently, but we have also experienced it at other times as well.

Using iOS 5 & 6, PhoneGap 2.1 and the OpenTok PhoneGap plugin.

Comment: Is this issue still happening with the latest PhoneGap version and the latest OpenTok plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When OpenTok runs, it opens up a view to capture video in order to stream it, putting the camera in video mode. When you then call navigator.device.capture.captureVideo, phonegap could be flipping the camera in their sdk but I dont know for sure.

Either way, this should be resolved with the latest OpenTok SDK and Cordova framework.